# @ResponseStatus - for custom response status code

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have the following line of code in controller class

`@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)`

Everything is simple and beautiful when the `HttpStatus` enum has the value I need. But today I needed status code`210`. And there is no such choice between `HttpStatus` enums value. Maybe you know a clean and tidy way (without directly constructing `HttpServletResponse`) how I can set the `210` status code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@ResponseStatus` only allows you to use `HttpStatus` as the parameter, and `HttpStatus` does not allow you to provide a custom code (it's an enum, so the set of values is fixed).

To return a custom status code, you'll need to change your controller method to return `ResponseEntity<YourResponseType>`, and then specify the code via `HttpStatusCode.valueOf`:

```java
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", HttpStatusCode.valueOf(210));
```

It is worth mentioning that 210 is not a [status code that is defined in the HTTP spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success) - if possible, you'd probably be better off changing to use a status code that more accurately  reflects the outcome of the API call. But I appreciate sometimes you have to do weird things when integrating systems :)